how to map/remap `t <` or `t [` in calc?
In calc, t [ jumps to the beginning of the trail. But in a regular buffer, M-< jumps to the beginning. I'd like t < to do what t [ does now.
How can I do that in a use-package :bind declaration? If I do
    (:map calc-mode-map
          ("t<" . calc-trail-first)
          ("t>" . calc-trail-last)

I get
Error (use-package): casual-calc/:catch: Key sequence t < starts with non-prefix key t"

How can I do this remapping?

Only one question per post, please.

The root cause here seems to be related to the funky way calc is loading its keybindings.
If I start emacs with no customization of calc (or casual-calc, which I'm also trying to use), then do M-x calc, and then do C-h k t to see about the t key in calc, I get this!
t runs the command calc-missing-key (found in calc-mode-map), which is
an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in ‘calc-misc.el’.

It is bound to C-k, C-w, C-M-w, M-k and M-w, and many ordinary text
characters.

(calc-missing-key N)

This is a placeholder for a command which needs to be loaded from calc-ext.
When this key is used, calc-ext (the Calculator extensions module) will be
loaded and the keystroke automatically re-typed.

If I hit t in calc, then run the above declaration, it works.
If I try that declaration before doing t in calc, it doesn't work -- it looks like that prefix doesn't even get defined until you do t in calc.
Since it seems that the t prefix keymap isn't defined until the calc-ext package gets loaded, the solution seems to be to use that:
(use-package calc-ext
  :defer t
  :bind (:map calc-mode-map
              ("t<" . calc-trail-first)
              ("t>" . calc-trail-last)
              ("t[" . calc-trail-scroll-left)
              ("t]" . calc-trail-scroll-right)))


Weird: the above works on Linux (Ubuntu 24.04); but now trying this on a Windows machine, it doesn't. I need to do :demand t to get the calc-ext package to load so that the prefix map gets defined. I haven't dug in to see if there's something different about my configuration, or if it's a version thing, or a Windows/Linux thing, or what.
But for anyone who finds the above doesn't work, trying :demand t to get it to load right away seems to be an option.

:defer is implied by :bind according to the doc. Since you need it loaded, :demand is the right way (and I was mistaken before in my - now deleted - answer).
